# Why won't UIDocumentInteractionController present a preview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios

We have a Monotouch application that contains a UIViewController that is used to present lists of files and allow the user to interact with files in the list.

In one of the interactions, we allow the user to view the file through the use of a UIDocumentInteractionController with calls to it PresentPreview method with the animated parameter set to true.

Now, our problem is that depending on the chain of events leading to the display of this view controller, PresentPreview may or may not be shown.

If this view controller is presented modally from a non-modal view controller, the preview works perfectly.

However, if another view controller is opened modally, and then our problem view controller is opened modally from that view controller, present preview does not work. There is no error message, the return value from the method is true, and the methods in the delegate are invoked correctly and in the same order as the first scenario, it's just that the document preview is never shown.

I have researched [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1) and found the following statement that seems to describe the problem:

> ... or if the view controller that your implementation returns is unable
>   to present another modal view controller, the document preview is not
>   displayed.

However, nowhere do they specify **why** a given view controller would be unable to present another modal view controller.

If anyone could shed any light on this, I would be very grateful.